# React: history.listen - How to unlisten?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On one module, I need to listen to the url change, so I wrote a simple code:

```
componentDidMount(){
        history.listen( location =>  {
            console.log('listen')
            doSomeStuff(location);
        });
    }
```

But after leaving the page where this module is used, I still see `console.log('listen)`, it turns out that the listener still performs a function `doSomeStuff(location)`, even where it is not necessary?

I read the documentation that says, quote:

> "When you attach a listener using history.listen, it returns a function that can be used to remove the listener, which can then be invoked in cleanup logic:"
>
> ```
> const unlisten = history.listen(myListener);
> // ...
> unlisten();
> ```

I do not understand what I need to write in `ComponentWillUnmount` to stop this listener.

I am using `2.8.0` version of `react-router`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to store the unlistener function in a variable in your class so you can call it from the other event

```
YourClass extends React {

  // ..
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unregisterHistoryListener = history.listen( location =>  {
      console.log('listen')
      doSomeStuff(location);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unregisterHistoryListener()
  }
}
```